# Do the Number of Columns "Slow Down" the Time Required for SQL Joins?

Tags: join

I am running the following SQL query using the R programming language to perform an inner join:

```
table_1 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "125"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_1$id = as.factor(table_1$id)
table_1$id2 = as.factor(table_1$id2)
table_1$date_1 = as.factor(table_1$date_1)

table_2 = data.frame(id = c("123", "123", "125", "125"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_2$id = as.factor(table_2$id)
table_2$id2 = as.factor(table_2$id2)
table_2$date_2 = as.factor(table_2$date_2)
table_2$date_3 = as.factor(table_2$date_3)

#SQL

library(sqldf)

sqldf("select distinct * 
  from table_1 a inner join table_2 b
  on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3) and 
     a.id = b.id or (a.id2 = b.id2)")
```

**My Question:** In my actual data, "table_1" and "table_2" contain around 20 columns each - however, most of these columns are not required for the "join". If I include all these columns (e.g. select * from table_1 vs. select id, date_1 from table_1) - can this make the "join" take a longer amount of time? Or does the computer ignore the other columns not required in the "join" and simply take the same amount of time whether all columns are included vs. only the required columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it depends on the indexes that exist on the table. For example, if SQL is able to perform an Index seek, and the index contains the columns needed, it could stop there and join the results together. In this scenario, including any number of the columns would not really change the duration of the query.

However, it would not be common to create a NONCLUSTERED index covering all columns. In this case, SQL would need to do the index seeks for the joins and follow that up with a Key Lookup to retrieve all columns. This would increase the duration of the query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't (for the most part) necessarily affect the performance of the `JOIN` operation itself but...**Yes, it slows down the total runtime of the query**, for the following reasons:

1. More columns is more data that needs to be: located from disk, read off of disk and likely written into memory, and finally read from memory and returned to the consuming client (likely across the network). Each of those resources have limitations, especially disk I/O generally being the biggest bottleneck.
2. Unneeded columns could eliminate the possible use of the most efficient query plan, ergo the most efficient way to serve the data to your query. This is because the extra columns being requested may not be part of the most optimal index for your query, resulting in the clustered index (or row id otherwise) to be used instead.
3. Similarly to reason #2, a less efficient index operation can be chosen such as a **scan** or **seek with key lookups** to locate the data for the unnecessary additional columns.
4. There could be an additional performance implications from waiting on requested resources (memory grants for example) for longer than necessary, because more resources are needed to serve the data of the additional columns you don't need.

`SELECT *` is a pretty bad anti-pattern / bad practice which you can read up on additional reasons why (besides my aforementioned points) in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321299/5059085).